# How to mix C++ and external buttons on seperate window?

Tags: c++

I want to make a `C++` button on Start>Run i.e but when I do it will not do signalled event?

Im sorry I have seen that you do not get the question.

Ok basically when you create a button with `CreateWindowEx()`; I want to do that but put on a different window with `SetPArent` which I have already done now the button does not work so I need my program to someone get when it is clicked from the Run window as example!

And yes you have it, but it's not making the button is the problem it's getting when it's clicked with my program since it does not belong to it anymore!

Comment: I thought programmign questions were aloowed here? Yet every time I ask one that is rightly worded i get voted -1. This is a question no matter what level you think of it.

Comment: The problem is we can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Do you mean: How do I add a button to the Start menu on Windows which has the label "C++"? Also, proper tagging helps the answers. HTH.

Comment: What is a "C++ button"?  Post code, use more than one "sentence" to explain what you are trying to do and be explicit about what is failing (do you get error messages, etc.?)

Comment: Also, and I mean this in the nicest possible way, your choice of handle is doing you no favors here.

Comment: Take all of the above as constructive criticism rather than a flaming. Maybe put yourself in our shoes and read the question back to yourself. Then rephrase and be as descriptive as you can about what you're trying to do. Then change your handle to something less befitting of a 15 year old wanna be hacker if you want to be taken seriously by us silly grownups.

Comment: Your profile says you're from the USA? Well, we can't all be native English (neither am I) making it hard to express oneself in a foreign language. Let me try: **you need a button on another window (which already works) and you want to be able to respond with some C++ code when the button is clicked (which doesn't work).** Correct? (if so, please edit your q. again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to apply the ancient but still-supported technique known in Windows as *subclassing*; it is well explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx) (15-years-old article, but still quite valid;-).  As this article puts it,

> Subclassing is a technique that allows
>   an application to intercept messages
>   destined for another window. An
>   application can augment, monitor, or
>   modify the default behavior of a
>   window by intercepting messages meant
>   for another window.

You'll want "instance subclassing", since you're interested only in a single window (either your new button, or, the one you've `SetParent`ed your new button to); if you decide to subclass a window belonging to another process, you'll also need to use the injection techniques explained in the article, such as, injecting your DLL into system processes and watching over events with a `WH_CBT` hook, and the like.  But I think you could keep the button in your own process even though you're `SetParent`ing it to a window belonging to a different process, in which case you can do your instance subclassing entirely within your own process, which is much simpler if feasible.

"Superclassing" is an alternative to "subclassing", also explained in the article, but doesn't seem to offer that many advantages when compared to instance subclassing (though it may compared with *global* subclassing... but, that's not what you need here anyway).

You'll find other interesting articles on such topics [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570(VS.85).aspx#subclassing_window), [here](http://www.aaronballman.com/programming/REALbasic/WindowSubclassingArticle.php), and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/Windows_subclassing.aspx) (developing a big, rich C++ library for subclassing -- but, also showing a simpler approach based on hooks which you might prefer).  Each article has a pretty difference stance and code examples, so I think that having many to look at may help you find the right mindset and code for your specific needs!

Comment: The beauty of Stackoverflow is that sometimes you get great answers, even when the original question was totally unintelligible...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll do my very best - as I understand you, you're trying to inject a button into some existing window. That meaning: Your tool creates a button in some window that does not belong to your application. Now, you want to be notified when that button is pressed. Am I correct so far?

To be notified about the button being pressed, you need to get the respective window message, which will only work if you also "inject" a different WndProc into the window. Actually I have no idea how that should work, but I faintly remember functions like `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`. Maybe they will help?

**EDIT**
I've searched MSDN a little: While you can get the address of a window's WndProc using `GetWindowLong`, you can not set the WndProc using `SetWindowLong` on Windows NT/2000/XP (and up I suppose). See [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx).

So what you could do is install a global message hook that intercepts *all* window messages, filter those for the window you've injected the button into and then find your message. If you have trouble with this, however, I'm the wrong person to ask, because it's been years ago since I've done anything like that, but it would be stuff for a new question.

**EDIT 2**
Please see Alex Martinellis answer for how to define the hook. I think he's describing the technique I was referring to when I talked about defining global message hooks to intercept the window messages for the window you injected your button into.